# Check all the checkboxes on basis of Id angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this array of objects. In each object there is another array.

```
panels = [{
  Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd",
  Name: "Celiac test",
  Tests: [{
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 1 (DGP) IgG"
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 2 (DGP) IgG"
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 3 (DGP) IgG"
    }
  ]
}, and so on],
```

I have mapped it to a bootstrap accordion with checkboxes.

First there is a checkbox for the main object, then checkboxes for the array within that object.

What I want is that when I click on the main Panel checkbox it should select the Tests checkboxes and save the panel object in the object variable, say **selectedPanel**, and when I deselect the main Panel it should deselect all the Tests checkboxes too.

but the main thing is that when I deselect one of the Tests checkboxes it should be removed from selectedPanel.

and the issue is it should be done on basis of **Id**, not checked/selected coming from backend.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

I have created a stackblitz too:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvbwtr)

Answer (score 0):

First create array which will hold selected checkboxes. This array will hold id of selected panels/tests.

```
selectedCheckboxes: [];
```

To make binding with checkbox "checked" attribute you will need another param to your object, let's call it "checked" for simplicity.

```
checked: true/false
```

In your HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-5" id="{{panel.Id}}" name="{{panel.Name}}" (change)="togglePanelCheck(panel)" [checked]="panel.checked">

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-5" id="{{test.Id}}" name="{{test.Name}}" [checked]="test.checked" (change)="toggleCheck(test)">
```

Code for toggle checking:

```
togglePanelCheck(panel){
   if(panel.checked){
     this.uncheckPanel(panel);
   } else {
     this.checkPanel(panel);
   }
}

checkPanel(panel){
  this.checkItem(panel);

  if(this.panelHasTests()){
    panel.tests.foreach(test => {
      this.checkItem(test);
    });
  }
}

uncheckPanel(){
  this.uncheckItem(panel);

  if(this.panelHasTests()){
    panel.tests.foreach(test => {
      this.uncheckItem(test);
    });
  }
}

toggleCheck(item){
  if(item.checked){
    this.uncheckItem(item);
  } else { 
    this.checkItem(item);
  }
}

checkItem(item){
  this.selectedCheckboxes.push(item.id);
  item.checked = true;
}

uncheckItem(item){
  const index = this.selectedCheckBoxes.indexOf(item.id);
  this.selectedCheckBoxes.splice(index, 1);
  item.checked = false;
}

private panelHasTests(panel) : boolean {
 return panel.tests && panel.tests.length != 0;
}
```

Comment: cant understand your code. for what purposes you are using selectDefaultChecked and getAllCheckedTestsFromPanel?

Comment: and also there is no checked value coming backend

Comment: I removed case with predefined checked items. But you still need "checked" property inside your object for binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `checkItem()` as below

```
checkItem(panel: any) {
  panel.isChecked = !panel.isChecked;
  panel.Tests.forEach(e => {
    e.isChecked = true;
  });
}
```

When you are done, your `panels` object will hold the statues of all checkboxes.

Comment: there is no isChecked value coming from backend. it will work at first but when i come again on the page where i have to select or deselect checkbox it will create problems for me